# 2013 Fusion running hot

Tags: ford, overheating, fusion

Car ran hot in less than 10 minute stop let it cool but when I started it said it was still hot. Also loss of power when I tried to make it home . Let the car sit again 2 full hours and the light still came on saying the car was hot. I am at a loss can’t think of what it could be. PLEASE HELP ME IF POSSIBLE ANYTHING APPRECIATED!!! Thank you 
Amanda

Comment: Welcome to the site! Did the light come on right away after the car sat for 2 hours, or did you drive it for awhile first?

Comment: No I did not drive anywhere ! It was like the light was stuck but when put it in gear it won’t move .

Comment: No problem @AmandaEberenz, you say when put into gear it won't move, do you mean the car won't roll at all? Does it actually start and run okay? Do you have any other warning lights on the dash, like the check engine light?

Comment: Yes had no problems and now give it gas and does nothing . Just says it’s over heating and has coolant

Comment: Check engine light on but it goes off and on all the time , I had the car a year today and nothing but problems

Comment: Is your car a selectshift system or a standard auto?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have 2 problems at first blush: the car's overheating light comes on even when the car's been sitting, and the car won't roll even though it's started. However, if I remember, newer Fords have a computerized gear selection system rather than using mechanical linkages, so the 2 could be related if there's a computer fault. Or it could be the computer isn't putting the car into gear because it has detected an error condition.

If a computer failure is causing both problems it's an expert job to fix it, or to replace it, if it's separate problems then each has a cause that can be independently solved. Taking the overheating problem first, if the light comes on even when the car is cool then it's most likely a problem with one of the  temperature sensors. That's good news if so, sensors are generally cheap to buy and easy to replace. I've been told there's a transmission solenoid that frequently causes issue with cars not going into gear, also a cheap and easy fix.

The best thing to do is get your cars On-Board Diagnostics (OBD2) codes read to find out what the computer is saying is wrong. If you can get your car moving then take to an auto parts store, many of them will do this for free. If it won't move you may have to pay for someone to come although you can buy a bluetooth reader and read the codes yourself for less than $20.

Comment: Thank you for your help I am going to try to get it to a professional looks like something I definitely can’t do alone

Comment: After ford took another look said head gasket s was blown and cheaper to replace the motor. Since I ended up letting the car go back . Auto touring was called your car in Orlando sells cars that are known to have problems. They would not work with me at all to fix the problems even tho the check engine light came on the day I drove it off the lot.

Answer (score 0):

It’s the engine coolant temperature sensor. When it goes bad it automatically registers as overheating. When that happens, the engine goes into failsafe mode which is why you can’t accelerate.